# catalog search is not working in magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I want to create a dedicated search on based of my products title only.
I removed the description from catalog search from backend but its also searching from the description and i cannot get my desired search things

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be more suitable to post this on http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i am on magento stackexchange but unfortunately i am not getting any answers from there.so i thought its a better idea to ask here. Sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when a customer uses the search function to find a product on your site not only product names are search for the word/phrase but also the short and detailed descriptions of products. If you want to disable the search function for product descriptions, you can do that by editing the settings of the attributes for the short and detailed description.

To do this in the admin panel of your Magento go to Catalog>Attributes>Manage Attributes. In the table on the following page find the description attribute and click on its name. On the page with its settings set the Use in Quick Search drop-down menu to No. If you want to disable it also in the advanced search, set the drop-down menu Use in Advanced Search to No. Then click on the Save Attribute button. Repeat the same steps for the short description attribute.

After that go to System>Index Management and reindex the data. Then go to the frontend of your site and test the results.

Comment: thank you! i have 1 more problem that i want that if i search galaxy core 2 then i want only result of galaxy core 2 .. but now its showing up other products along with my search .how to disable these function

Comment: By default Magento does not provide the exact match search. To achieve Exact Match search functionality  check http://www.tricksofit.com/2014/10/exact-match-search-in-magento#.Vt_e2kKli1E